# Spybot Search and Destroy Open Proxy?

Tags: proxy-server, spybot-sd

Does Spybot Search and Destroy (v2.2) run an active open proxy on computers it's installed to?

Comment: 1. Why would it? 2. Why do you ask?

Comment: @joeqwerty I work at a IT department and apparently there have been a few abuse complaints. The common pattern is Spybot S&D.

Comment: No; of course it doesn't

Comment: Well if it's installed on a Windows OS then fire up Microsoft Network Monitor and see if the Spybot S&D process is generating network traffic or is in the listening state. You could also run `netstat -a -n -o >C:\netstat.txt` from a command prompt to capture network connection info to a text file.

Comment: @joeqwerty I'll try that out.

Comment: @joeqwerty I saw a few S&D services listening at 0.0.0.0:21321 and set Firefox to use that address as a proxy. Firefox said the proxy refused to connect me when I tried accessing superuser.com, but it was fine connecting and searching on Google.

Comment: Redact that last one, Google searching works but trying to access google.com doesn't work. I'm guessing the search function doesn't use a proxy if one is configured.

Comment: Something to check: http://forums.spybot.info/showthread.php?69728-SDFSSvc-exe-Gone-Rogue